# Math operations inside where claue of rails

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The table(days_of_weeks) contains 8 columns , one is id, and rest constitues the days of week (sun,mon,tue ...) where the days of week holds either 0 or 1

I need to find rows whose sum of days of week is less than 3.

As a sql statement i can write

```
select id  from days_of_week where (mon + tue + wed + thu + fri + sat + sun ) < 3;
```

I'm trying to query it from rails

```
DaysOfWeek.select(:id).where((:sun + :tue + :wed + :thu + :fri + :sat + :sun) < 3)
```

it shows error because its just a symbol, i tried .to_i , but with no luck.

I know i can directly query with a sql statement from rails, but i want to do it the rails? way.

Any solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is common to write String conditions in `.where` clause in ActiveRecord, would the following be considered as "a sql statement"?

```rb
DaysOfWeek.select(:id).where('(mon + tue + wed + thu + fri + sat + sun ) < 3')
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a commonly used query, you can add a column, say `total` and keep it updated using a callback.

Could be like

```
before_save :update_total

def update_total
  self.total = mon + tue + wed + thu + fri + sat + sun
end
```